# How to split slash / separated string in two variable in php

Tags: php

Assume that applicant id was passed from the other form.I have array variable coming from my database, here is the code :

```
$array_id_applicants = explode(";",stripslashes($applicant_id1));
$applicants_num = count($array_id_applicants);
$arr_app_num = array();
for($x=0;$x<=$applicants_num;$x++) 
{ 
if($array_id_applicants[$x]){
 $applicant_id = str_replace("'","",$array_id_applicants[$x]);

 $applicants = getdata("select cellphone from personal where applicant_id='".$applicant_id."'");
$replace_array = array("-","(",")","+","_");
array_push($arr_app_num,str_replace($replace_array,"",$applicants[1][cellphone]));
 }
}
$applicant_number = implode(";",$arr_app_num);
echo $applicant_number; exit;
```

Assume that this is the value of array :

```
$applicant_number = '639152478931 / 631687515455','631235497891'
```

I want the output to be like this :

```
$applicant_number = '639152478931','631687515455','631235497891'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <?php
    $applicant_number[] = '639152478931';
$applicant_number[] = '631235497891';
$applicant_number[] = '1111111110294765388389';
$applicant_number[] = '0012324252728';
$new    =   array();
foreach($applicant_number as $number) {           
            $count = strlen($number) - 10;              
            $b = substr($number,$count);                
     $new[]  = "+63".$b;        
    }   
print_r($new);
                ?>
```

**Gives you :**

Array ( [0] => +639152478931 [1] => +631235497891 [2] => +634765388389 [3] => +632324252728 )

Comment: Thank you agapitz. it works great :) however i change you code a little bit to make your array to be a string `$arr_app_split = split(";",$applicant_number);

foreach($arr_app_split as $number) {           
$count = strlen($number) - 10;  
$b = substr($number,$count);  
$new_applicant_number[]  = "63".$b; 
} 
$new = implode(";",$new_applicant_number);`

Answer (score 1):

See if this is what you are trying to do.:

```
<?php
    $applicant_number[] = '639152478931 / 631687515455';
    $applicant_number[] = '631235497891';
    $applicant_number[] = '0294765388389 / 52525252525';
    $applicant_number[] = '0012324252728';

    $new    =   array();

    foreach($applicant_number as $number) {
            if(strpos($number,'/') !== false) {
                    $val    =   explode("/",str_replace(" ","",$number));
                    $new    =   array_merge($new,$val);
                }
            else
                $new[]  =   $number;
        }

    print_r($new);
?>
```

**Gives you:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 639152478931
    [1] => 631687515455
    [2] => 631235497891
    [3] => 0294765388389
    [4] => 52525252525
    [5] => 0012324252728
)
```

Comment: It was great sir . :) thank you a lot. Sir how about i want to replace the 63 into 0 ?

Comment: The 63 at the beginning of each value?